# Test Results and Documentation Site

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, karma-jasmine, xunit, istanbul

Currently i am using these tools to run my tests,code coverage and documentation:

**Unit testing:**

- jasmine
- xUnit

**Code Coverage:**

- Istanbul
- dotCover

**Documentation:**

- Typedoc

As i'm trying to do everything modular for both frontend and backend we have multiple bower components and nuget packages where of course each components runs different type of tests and documentation.

Now what i want to do is to have a dedicated site which grabs all test results  and documentation and have a dedicated site where all developers etc. can use it as a point of reference.

Is there any plugin available that can help me achieve it?

if not do you have any idea from where can i start as i tried googling a bit but with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using roughly the same technologies. 
As a build server I use TeamCity.
In a nutshell: your build is composed by steps, e.g (simplified):

1. build .sln
2. gulp build
3. xUnit tests (*A: [publishing coverage](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Manually+Configuring+Reporting+Coverage))
4. karma run
5. remap coverage from Javascript to Typescript (*B: publish coverage)

The only problem I had so far is with the coverage (*A + *B). The last data will overwrite the first one, (not average it all). So in that case I use [custom reports page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results) to display the istanbul generated html report and only use the xUnit coverage report.

You could have the coverage.json from istanbul as an artifact of your build, and a second build picks up and reports that coverage through teamcity. It would be simply a coverage report build (only 1 step, report code coverage). The trigger is a successful build generating the coverage.

For your generated documentation you can also use [custom reports page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results).

About the unit tests execution (both jasmine (karma?) and xunit), both report its numbers and the final Test report will show them combined.

Comment: but like that you have the documentation being generated on each build right? Wouldn't it make more sense to have a seperate site to host all your documentation?

Comment: For that kind of documentation (generated out of code comment) each commit potentially changed the documentation. The target audience are the developers so personally I see TeamCity as a great place to 'host' it. As your application evolves, so does the API documentation and different branches have different content. You could use TC generate an artifact from the documentation and publish on another server though.

Comment: How do you generate the documentation for the unit tests? For the plan, not for report execution